# Get a particular page content from old_text column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

What I am trying to do is to get a telephone contact list from a page content.

All my pages are stored in a database, which I have successfully accessed using Code Igniter.

I want to output a telephone contact list as HTML table. This list is located on one of the pages. The content of this page is saved as BLOB type in the old_text column of the table text in my MySQL database.

I know the old_id value of my page in the table text. I think it might be useful.

How can I find this contact list using MYSQL commands in php script?

Here is my code how I have selected the old_text value of the page where the telephone contact list is.

Code Igniter Controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller{
  public function index(){
     $data['record'] = $this->db->query('SELECT old_text FROM text WHERE old_id = 862');
     $this->load->view('home',$data);
  }
}
```

Code Igniter View home.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    <?php print_r($record);?>
    </div>  
</body>


</html>
```

And I have got as an output:

> CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #28 [result_id] => Resource id #29 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 [row_data] => )

The reason for this output in my oppinion might be the fact that the old_text content as BLOB type encoded is.

I have also tried the following command in order to return BLOB field as a varchar, but I have got the same output.

```
SELECT cast(old_text AS char) FROM text WHERE old_id = 862
```

Comment: You probably have a problem of vocabulary here: a *[database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)* store several *[tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28database%29)* which in their turn have *[columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_%28database%29)* (the "fields name") and *[rows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_%28database%29)* (the "values"). Apparently there are some confusions about that in your question. If you expect most meaningfull answers, I think you should edit your question to fix that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to improve my question.

Comment: Provide a sample of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the output, $data['record'] is a CI_DB_mysql_result Object.

So you will "get" data from this object. Assuming you only have 1 result you have to do:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
     $res = $this->db->query('SELECT old_text FROM text WHERE old_id = 862');
     if ($res->num_rows() > 0)
     {
        $data['record'] = $res->row(); 
     }
     else
     {
        $data['record'] = "no result";
     }
     $this->load->view('home',$data);
  }
}
```

If you have multiple result you have to loop on the $res.

You can take a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: Dragu, many thanks for the answer! You have helped me a lot! Have a nice new week!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you validate my answer please ?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but I am not allowed to vote because of my low reputation :(